# Need to send an email via Microsoft Graph API with HTML and a Table in the body

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I need to send HTML emails via Microsoft Graph API in Powershell, but I also need to have a table in the email body that is created from a CSV file. I'm able to send an HTML email, but no matter how I try to create the table I get a Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I need to be able to generate a new table via a for-each as there are several versions of this table with different data in them.

I have tried:

1. Joining the body of the email with a variable holding the table in HTML form.
2. Creating a text file with the body of the email in it (including the table)and grabbing the body content via Get-Content.
3. Creating the table in the script before the variable containing the mail body is called.

Each of these have resulted in the same 400 error. Has anyone had success with this?

My actual script does have all the necessary variables filled in. I've removed the tenant ID etc, etc in this post.

```
Write-Host "`r`nEnter the name of the file you want to" -NoNewLine; Write-Host " import" -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline; Write-Host " without the file extension:"
    Write-Host ""
    $InputFileName = Read-Host
    Write-Host ""

  $Script:Users = import-csv "C:\temp\$InputFileName.csv"

  $Script:Users | Sort-Object -Property Manager,Name | Group-Object -Property Manager | ForEach-Object {
        $Managername = $_.name

        $HTMLBody = "
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        Table {
          border-collapse: collapse;
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
        TH{
          border: 1px solid black;
          background-color dddddd;
          padding: 5px;
        }
        TD{
          border: 1px solid black;
          padding: 5px;
        }
        BODY{
          font-family: Calibri;
          Font-size: 11pt;
        }

        </style>
        </head>

        <p>List of users that have access to PSI:</p>
         '<p>Above you will find a list that details your staff members who have access to PSI. The access review is to confirm that access is appropriate for each individual. 
        
        <b><h3>The key below describes what actions users can take in the given system.</b></h3>
        
        $($_.group | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment)

        </p>
        </html>
        "
      }
$clientID = ""
$Clientsecret = ""
$tenantID = ""
$FromAddress = ""
$MailSubject = "Test Email - Graph API"
$ToAddress = ""
$bodycontent4 = "$HTMLBody"

#Connect to GRAPH API
$tokenBody = @{
  Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
  Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
  Client_Id     = $clientId
  Client_Secret = $clientSecret
}
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $tokenBody
$headers = @{
  "Authorization" = "Bearer $($tokenResponse.access_token)"
  "Content-type"  = "application/json"
}
#Send Mail    
$URLsend = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$FromAddress/sendMail"
$Body =
@"
{
  "message": {
    "subject": "$mailSubject",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "HTML",
      "content": "$bodyContent4"
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address":, "$ToAddress"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveToSentItems": "false"
}                 
"@

Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Uri $URLsend -Body $Body -Method POST
```

Comment: Don't build the json manually as a string: create a psobject and serialize this to json. Json is a serialization technique and should be used in that way. The problem you're encountering has to do with the fact that a lot of the strings in the html lack the proper escapes (this is ons of the reasons why you should serialize/deserialize instead of trying to build a json document by manipulating strings). You must also specify the content-type when posting json to Graph

Comment: I don't know anything about JSon, Could you provide some clarification on what you mean? Or even a resource for this?

Comment: @bluuf I found some articles to review for this. Thank you for the guidance!
I'll be going over this one tomorrow [link](https://hayato-iriumi.net/2019/07/04/powershell-custom-object-to-and-from-json/)

Comment: There is a lot of documentation online about json. Look for Convertto-Json. I also noticed that your invoke-restmethod didn't specify the -contenttype parameter (this should be set to application/json), Graph will always return a 400 if you post data without specifying the contenttype (because invoke-restmethod reverts to formbased by default)

Answer (score 2):

My issue ended up being that there was some small issue with the formatting of my body content (the `$body = @"`). As far as getting the table into the email, I had to `Get-content` to pull in a text document with HTML formatting in it and then convert it into HTML.

```
$importbodycontent = Get-Content "C:\Temp\$bodydocument.txt" -raw 
$importbodycontent | ConvertTo-Html | Out-Null
```

After that I used a text replacement to replace certain text with the contents of the HTML table that I created.

```
$groupcontents = $_.group | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
$Currentbodycontent = $importbodycontent.replace('TABLEGOESHERE', $groupcontents)
$bodycontent3 = "$Currentbodycontent"
```

Then I was able to use that content in the body of the email, and get it to send properly.

```
  $Body =
  @"

{
  "message": {
    "subject": "$mailsubject",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "HTML",
      "content": "$bodycontent3"
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "$toaddress"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
}
                      
"@
  Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Uri $URLsend -Body $Body -Method POST
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to send the e-mail is most of it done.
For converting PSObjects in html tables you can use the ConvertTo-Html cmdlet.

If you use the ConvertTo-Html as is, it will generate the output as if it is a new HTML document.
If you need to insert this table on a already existing HTML, use the -Fragment switch parameter.
Something like this:

```
$object = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Path\To\Your\File.csv'

Body = @"
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <head>
                <style>
                table, th, td {
                  border-collapse: collapse;
                  text-align: left;
                  padding-right: 15px;
                }
                tr:nth-child(odd) {
                      background-color: #D6EEEE;
                }
                th {
                    background-color: #8fbfbf;
                }
                tr:last-child {
                    background-color: #8fbfbf;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
                p {
                    margin: 0;
                    font-size: 1.5em;
                  }
                </style>
                </head>
                
                Your usual HTML stuff.
                The table:
                
                $($object | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment)

                </html>
"@
```

Comment: I tried adding your version of the convertto-html and I still receive the 400 error.

Comment: So you need to take a step back and look to your request. 400 is Bad Request or Bad Request Format. Take a look  if the token from the first POST is in the format you expect or if something in the message is not right

Comment: This Ms Graph is quite new for me, so sorry if you already went through it. Have you took a look at the Microsoft.Graph PS module?

Install-Module Microsoft.Graph